# html agility pack parsing error?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm working on a few hundred pages of amazon search results for some data analysis, and using hap to parse out the results:

```
hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']/li")
```

This only returns the first four li's of the result list though when there are more. I've checked and double checked and I'm sure this is right - am I doing something very wrong? I can't see why the results are limited to just 4. Typical page content might be: https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=100+percent+barstow

Using other search results pages give the same problem and do not give the results on the page, but always significantly less than what's there.

Comment: Maybe this page loads on demand, given the scroll, then your are not getting the entire result.

Comment: @Fals I thought that too, but checked the html output that it's parsing and it's all there. If I change the `SelectNodes` to something looser, then 21 nodes (each listing on the page) is captured.

Comment: Just try out another selector, like id containing result_.

Comment: As above. Either 4 nodes or 21 nodes when there should be 12

Comment: @user3791372 I checked the amazon page and did a CTRL+F on the page source and only found like 3 nodes

Comment: @user3791372 Don't really have time to take a look at it thoroughly but can you check that you don't also want <ul class="s-result-list s-col-1 s-col-ws-1 s-result-list-hgrid s-height-equalized s-list-view s-text-condensed"> ?

Comment: @Tyress The id declaration should be fine to select the ul. Not show how you did a ctrl+f but there are more than 3 li nodes in the ul!

Comment: @user3791372 I looked for the ul id and took the li's inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@id,'tfResults')]//li[contains(@class,'s-result-item')]");
```

No guarantees for other pages though because I'm only basing on the link you gave

Comment: +1 because I learnt that you could use contains to capture part of values (e.g. atfResults / btfResults) would be caught by the above which is what's needed! Thanks